# Not able to get the correct revision number

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to echo the revision number of the build i am building . In the execute shell box, I am using the SVN environment variable SVN_REVISION. But all the time it echoes a smaller number than the  one I see in the console output 
Example: In console output i see, **At revision 1234**. But when I echo, SVN_REVISION I see 1232. Please tell me why I am not getting the correct revision number. I need to do this in order to organize the binaries as per the revision number

Comment: [If you use Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18714)

Answer (score 0):

Not really too much information going on. There's no automatic SVN_REVISION variable. Is this part of your build system? Where is this being set? How is it being set?

it is very likely that your last trunk revision is at 1232, but your repository revision is at revision 1234. Remember that the entire repo has one revision number. Someone making a change on a branch or in another project will up your revision number. However, the *last change* revision on the branch may well be two or more revisions behind.

You may want to look into [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to help you do your builds and track your revisions.

Comment: Hi, I am using Jenkins tool. It does provide the set of implicit environment variables-, here is the link          https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. Jenkins does have a SVN_REVISION variable. Jenkins can trigger the build after a commit, and it should be the latest revision at the time the build is triggered. I suspect that you're looking at the last revision when you look at Trunk and not the Last changed rev. In SVN, these are not necessarily the same thing.